# Casting and ArrayList

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList that contains a number of songs objects.

```
ArrayList<Song> aSong = new ArrayList<Song>();
```

The Song class looks like this:

```
public class Song {
private String sName;
private String sLength;

public Song(String name, String length){
    sName = name;
    sLength= length;

}

public String getName(){
    return sName;

}   

public String getLength(){

    return sLength;
}


public void edit(String name, String length){
    sName = name;
    sLength= length;
}
```

}

I'm trying to see if a song exists with the ArrayList method "contains"

```
   // example
   aSong.contains("Song 1")
```

but this returns false even though the song does really exist in the ArrayList.

Any help would be highly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, `"Song 1"` definitely doesn't exist in the `ArrayList` - because that's a *string*, not a *`Song`*.

Three options:

- Check for each song in the list to see whether it has that name. This is reasonably easy to do, but if you need that functionality in multiple places you'd definitely want to extract it into a separate method. Something like:

  ```
  public static Song findSongByName(Iterable<? extends Song> songList,
                                    String name)
  {
      // TODO: Nullity checks
      for (Song song : songList)
      {
          if (song.getName().equals(name))
          {
              return song;
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
  ```
- Override `equals` in `Song` based on the name of the song, and then call `aSong.contains(new Song("Song 1")`. This probably *isn't* a good idea, as I suspect that if you've got two `Song` objects with the same name but different lengths, you don't want to consider them as equal.
- Build a `Map<String, Song>` so that you can look up songs in the list based on their name. This would be a good idea if you needed to look up multiple songs from the same list.

Comment: Why would OP need to add in checks to determine the dimension of the subspace whose vectors result in the 0-vector under this particular linear transformation? (*hopes Jon Skeet appreciates linear algebra jokes*)

Comment: @dlev: That certainly isn't the *first* thing that came to my mind when writing that comment...

Comment: Thank Jon Skeet. Really appreciate your help. God Bless You

Comment: Oh... if only Java had Scala's implicit conversions!

Comment: @Bruno: Usage of implicit conversions is highly discouraged for such purposes.

Answer (score 1):

"Song 1" is a string, it's not the same as any Song object. Sounds to me that you are still at the stage where you think the language can guess what you want, rather than realising you have to tell it **exactly** and **precisely** what you want.

You could write a for loop and go though your list one by one, looking for the right title. Or perhaps you should switch to using a `HashMap<String, Song>`, that would let you look up a song by it's title.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function `find` that searches for and returns the first object that satisfies the given predicate.

```
public static <A> A find(final Iterable<A> iterable, final Predicate<A> predicate) {
  for(final A item : iterable) {
    if(predicate.isSatisfiedBy(item)) {
      return item;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

where `Predicate` is:

```
interface Predicate<A> {
  boolean isSatisfiedBy(final A a);
}
```

You could use this function for your purpose as shown below:

```
final Song song = find(songs, 
  new Predicate<Song>() {
    boolean isSatisfiedBy(final Song s) {
      return s.getName().equals("Song 1");
    }
  }
);
```